# Is polymorphic the best choice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys, i'm creating a browser game where battles between monsters and users(pvp) take place. The Monster model has all the functions that relate to the battle against monsters. I'm now creating the PvP system and the battle system is the same as in Monsters. So, i was thinking of creating some sort of an abstract presentation of the battle, maybe a Combatable Model (?) and make a polymorphic association.

Do you think this is the strategy i should follow, or i could do it in a better manner ?

Comment: If it's the same battle system, one should be using the same code to run it. No use reinventing the same code, or copying and pasting it and having to maintain it in two places, that's just means more bugs.

Comment: You haven't understood my question. Of course, the code is the same, but it resides in the Monster model, because it refers to monster. I would not want to use a Monster model call for pvp battles.

Comment: learn OOP, that's what inheritance is for. It shouldn't be in the monstor module, but a single generic shared one.

Comment: learn Rails, because you have absolutely no idea what you are talking about. I bet money that you do not even know what Rails is, based on your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you should create a Combatant class or module that you can inherit from or include in your Person and Monster classes, but you shouldn't persist a polymorphic association into the database. You should only use two tables: people and monsters.

```
module Combatant
...
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Combatant
  ...
end

class Monster < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Combatant
  ...
end
```

Comment: I must admit that this sounds like the way to go. Indeed, i only want a monster and a person model. Thanks by a greek, to another greek ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Single Table Inheritance](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=3815)

```
class Combatant < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Has all the fields we care about and basic damage rules, etc
end

class Person < Combatant
    # Any functions that only players can do
end

class Monster < Combatant
    # any functions that need to be overridden
end
```